# 3 Amps and 5 volts needed but don't know how to obtain

Tags: voltage, sensor, amperage, circuit-design

I am creating a circuit that detects ozone gas. The gas sensor requires a 5 volt supply and at least 3 amps. How do I get these amounts using batteries? I have researched how many amps different batteries used and I thought I would go with 3 triple-a batteries in parallel so that I would achieve a 3 amp circuit, but then I realized I would still only have a 1.5 voltage. What am I missing here that would solve my problem, how do I get the desired voltage with at least 3 amps ?

Link to data sheet to one of the sensors that I would be using -

https://www.seeedstudio.com/depot/datasheet/MQ-2.pdf

Comment: If you want this circuit to work for more than a short period of time, you either need a ton of battery, or to find a way to plug your device in.

Comment: It is suppose to be a mobile gas sensor, what would be a way of doing this ?

Comment: It wouldn't be located near an AC power source.

Comment: Can you provide us a full name of the sensor you are using so that we can see it's required current and voltage throught the datasheet...... I dont know much about the sensor but I doubt that it needs 3A current...

Comment: How long do you expect to need to power the device before recharging / replacing batteries?

Comment: I will in a minute, I watched a youtube video about using the sensor. I wanted to see their configuration. Maybe I was misguided. I will add the link to the post.

Comment: I'd expect to use that much power to create ozone, not measure it.

Comment: The amount of time I need to power it would be around 30 minutes to an hour. It will be used to measure ozone amounts in and around a city in an attempt to find problematic areas.

Comment: Did not read all of the data sheet but saw this "Preheat time Over 48 hours" and that the heater is <= 900mW @ 5 VAC or DC which is around 180mA; so not sure where the 3 amps comes from.

Comment: According to the datasheet, the heater requires about 150 mA, not 3 Amps, which eases the battery capacity requirement significantly.

Comment: The 3 amps is from a youtube video, I am unsure where they got it from. I know this is a different question now, but how do you change the amount of amps in a voltage fixed scenario ?

Comment: You can use a 1000A 5V supply for the sensor. It will happily draw 150mA all day long. I = E*R. However if you drop a wrench across the bus bars you`ll notice a difference.

Comment: Its always good to read the datsheets of your device before you start doing anything

Comment: Thank you very much for all of the help. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

The typical combustible gas sensor you linked to requires 150mA at 5V (33 ohms for the heater). I don`t see ozone listed.

You should be able to power that particular sensor from a rechargeable lithium cell or some AA alkaline batteries for the required time- just use an appropriate boost, buck-boost or buck converter depending on your battery voltage range.

In fact, if you want to minimize your work, you could use a USB power bank directly.

Comment: I do apologize, I got a link for the data sheet off of the youtube video I watched that utilized this sensor.

Comment: @NicholasMcCann - That still doesn't explain why you want to use it to detect ozone, even though the data sheet does not mention ozone as a detectible gas. Worse, the concentrations the data sheet deals with are typically 100s to 1000s ppm (parts per million) while ozone limits are typically under 100 ppb (parts per billion)! Why do you think this part will do what you want?

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast Even 100 ppm ozone for a sustained period is probably in the LD 50 range for humans.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany - The standard I saw was 70ppb for 8 hours.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast One reference says 50pm for 60 min is"probably fatal"

Comment: @SpehroPefhany - Yeah. Which is why I wondered about the utility of a sensor which seems to work in the high ppm range. A warning which alerts you to the fact that you're about to die doesn't seem all that useful.